# Google Forms/Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to link several google forms to one google sheet without separate tabs. I am creating a database so I want different employees to be responsible for different sections of the same spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "IMPORTRANGE". I had to do that recently. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en You have to tell the receiving sheet what range of the feeder sheets to import and then give permission.The trick is, if someone adds columns to a feeder sheet, you have to make sure the data is not "overlapping" in the receiving sheet. Otherwise, you'll get an error.